# Wysiwyg javascript редактор

Tags: wysiwyg, html, javascript

Добрый вечер

Я пишу движок небольшого блога
И мне требуется сделать простенький редактор Wysiwyg
Использовать готовые движки не хочу

Нужны просто кнопочки как вот тут сверху
(жирный, курсив, зачеркнутый, загрузка картинки на сервер, вставка ссылки, список, выравнивание, заголовок, шрифт, размер шрифта)

В итоге статья в базу должна приходить в виде html кода

Как сделать эти кнопочки
Может есть простенький качественный редактор на чистом javascript или какой нибудь кросбраузерный мануал?

В качестве примера нужно чтото типа такого локаничного
http://imperavi.com/redactor/
ноон платный и на jquery

Answer (score 1):

Он (`redactor`) на [`github`](https://github.com/yiiext/imperavi-redactor-widget) есть, OEM-версия.

Answer (score 0):

Надо определится как-то: 
1) >>> Использовать готовые движки не хочу 
2) Может есть простенький качественный редактор на чистом javascript 
Так все таки готовый или самописный. Если готовый советую checkeditor

Answer (score 0):

https://quilljs.com/
гибко настраиваемый редактор с кучей тем и дополнений